# Is there a way to update/return elements in an array from a method?

Tags: c, arrays

I would normally just use pointers but in this situation I am kind of stuck. Because the the element of the array is being pass in a 'random' order, I can't seem to figure out how to set `w` (from method update) back to `in[0]` (from method pass)

```
int main(){
   unsigned int array[4] = {
      0x10101010, 
      0x10101010,
      0x10101010, 
      0x10101010};

   pass(array);
}

void pass(unsigned int *a){

   update(a[0],a[1],a[4],a[3]);
   printf("%lu\t %lu\t %lu\t %lu\n",a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3]);  //how would I get the updated value here

   update(a[1],a[0],a[3],a[4]);
   printf("%lu\t %lu\t %lu\t %lu\n",a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3]);  //and here
}


/*update method could be of any type like int update(...) or whatever else*/
void update(w,x,y,z){ 
   w = z+2;
   x = x+1;
   y = y+2;
   z = w+1;
}
```

*Any* advice or help would be much appreciated it.

P.S the code above is something I just made up for example purpose.

Edit * printf should have used the %u instead of long unsigned (%lu). 
There are no type specifiers on update because K&R C (very old).

Comment: `void update(w,x,y,z){ ` doesn't look like C. guess you wanted something like `void update(unsigned int& w, unsigned int& x, unsigned int& y, unsigned int& z){ `

Comment: @user3365922 This is flagged as `c` not `c++` - does `c` have 'pass by reference'?

Comment: oh, it has no pass by reference

Comment: @user3365922 What you wrote looks even less like C. It's C++ but that's a different language. The code in question is actually valid C in some ancient (1980s) dialects (where the type of arguments defaults to `int`, though most of those didn't have `void`).

Comment: And the `//` comment wasn't valid in C89, and the types of arguments to printf are wrong and and...

Comment: `%lu` does print a **long unsigned int** which is distinct from **unsigned int**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass **pointers** to your `update` function and dereference them inside that function:

```
    void update(unsigned int* w, unsigned int* x, unsigned int* y, unsigned int* z){ 
       *w = *z+2;
       *x = *x+1;
       *y = *y+2;
       *z = *w+1;
    }
```

Then call `update` with the array elements' addresses:

```
update(&a[0], &a[1], &a[4], &a[3]);
```

Comment: Okay Ill give this a try.

Comment: I didn't get the right answer but the values did change lol. Ill figure out the rest. Thank you.

Comment: This most probably doesn't do what OP wants because it does lose the original values in the middle.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - Yes, I spotted that! But I just changed the ***original*** `update` function body to use dereferenced pointers. Local temporary variables may fix the problem.

Comment: @User - Maybe (as hinted in previous comment, and by **Antti**) the problem is that the line `*z = *w+1` is using a value of `w` that has already been changed?

Comment: @Adrian yeah after debugging my code, thats whats happening. Its using the changed value.

Comment: @Adrian Your original answer was correct before the edit. The error was on my end. My print statement was using %llu when i need to use %llx. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For starters this function declaration is incorrect because there is no type specifiers for parameters.

```
void update(w,x,y,z){ 
   w = z+2;
   x = x+1;
   y = y+2;
   z = w+1;
}
```

If you want to update passed to the function objects then they should be passed by reference through pointers.

The function can look the following way

```
void update( unsigned int *w, unsigned int *x, unsigned int *y,unsigned int *z )
{ 
   *w = *z+2;
   *x = *x+1;
   *y = *y+2;
   *z = *w+1;
}
```

> /*update method could be of any type*/

The function can not be declared like for example

```
void update( void *w, void *x, void *y, void *z );
```

because within the function you need to know the actual types of the arguments.

You could define the function the following way

```
void update( void *w, void *x, void *y, void *z, void sum( void *item, void *value ) );
```

That is with one addition parameter that has a function type. The corresponding function used as an argument could cast the pointer to the required type and perform the addition.

Also these calls of `printf` are incorrect

```
printf("%lu\t %lu\t %lu\t %lu\n",a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3]);
printf("%lu\t %lu\t %lu\t %lu\n",a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3]);
```

because there are used wrong conversion format specifiers for objects of the type unsigned int. Use `%u` instead of `%lu`.

Pay attention to that the functions `pass` and `update` shall be declare before their calls for example before the function `main`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I changed the printf to %u and used pointers. Im using K&R C so thats why there is no type specifier on the update method. I also meant update method can be changed to other type like int update or whatever else, if it made a difference. Thanks again